# Send e-mail message: "Failed to connect to mailserver"

Tags: php, sendmail

I try to use mail function to send e-mail in php when i use my code i have error message

```
Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()
```

This is the line for error message

```
$success = mail($mailto, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);
```

how to solve it , help please

Comment: Solution 1. *read* the error message, 2. *search* for the error message, 3. configure server correctly based upon research ..

Comment: I search but can't solve the error

Comment: Well, what have you tried to solve the error? (Include it in the post.)

Comment: `Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25` <- no SMTP server running on your `localhost` ... you can't use the `mail` function if you don't have a valid `SMTP` server

Comment: @txtechhelp how i can run mail server in my localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not running an incoming mail server (listening on SMTP port 25) on your machine (where the PHP script is executed), which it happens to connect to by default.

If you can install a SMTP server locally easily, e.g. in Linux by installing a "sendmail" package, you can solve it like that.

If you don't want to run such a server, you must at least modify your `php.ini` to set a SMTP server of your internet or mail provider instead. Search for `smtp` in the .ini file and fill the variables accordingly.